# Поиск узла бинарного дерева

Tags: c, поиск, дерево

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#define BUFF 256

typedef struct node {
    char* pnomber;
    int count;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
} Node;

    Node* AddNode(Node* Root, char* w) {
        int cond;
        if (Root == NULL) {
            Node* Root = malloc(sizeof(Node));
            Root->count = 1;
            Root->pnomber = strdup(w);
            Root->left = Root->right = NULL;
            return Root;
        }
        else if ((cond = strcmp(w, Root->pnomber)) == 0) {
            Root->count++;
        }
        else if (cond < 0)
            Root->left = AddNode(Root->left, w);
        else
            Root->right = AddNode(Root->right, w);
        return Root;
    }
    
    Node* PrintWood(Node* Root) {
        if (Root != NULL) {
            PrintWood(Root->right);
            printf("pnomber-->%s, count-->%d\n", Root->pnomber, Root->count);
            PrintWood(Root->left);
        }
        else return 0;
    }


    Node* SearchCount(Node* Root) {
        Node* SC = NULL;
        SC = Root;

        if (SC == NULL) { return SC; }
        else {
            if (SC->count >= 2)
                printf("pnomber-->%s, count->%d", SC->pnomber, SC->count);
                //printf("\n");
            SC->left = SearchCount(SC->left);
            SC->right = SearchCount(SC->right);
        }
        return SC;
    }

    Node* RootDelete(Node* Root/*, int count*/) {
        Node* LM = NULL; // Локальный минимум
        Node* SN = NULL; // Найденый узел
        Node* TMP = NULL;
        SN = SearchCount(Root); //Удаляемый элемент
        printf("\n");
        printf("pnomberSN-->%s, count-->%d\n", SN->pnomber, SN->count);
        
        return SN;
    }
    /*
    void DeleteWood(Node *Root) {
        if(Root != NULL) {
            DeleteWood(Root->left);
            DeleteWood(Root->right);
            free(Root);
        }
    } */

    int main() {
        
        Node* Root = NULL;

        Root = AddNode(Root, "Number5");
        Root = AddNode(Root, "Number5");
        Root = AddNode(Root, "Number7");
        Root = AddNode(Root, "Number22");
        Root = AddNode(Root, "Number25");
        Root = AddNode(Root, "Number27");
        Root = AddNode(Root, "Number10");
        Root = AddNode(Root, "Number10");
        Root = AddNode(Root, "Number15");
        Root = AddNode(Root, "Number18");
        Root = AddNode(Root, "Number3");
        Root = AddNode(Root, "Number1");
        Root = AddNode(Root, "Number13");
        Root = AddNode(Root, "Number13");
        Root = AddNode(Root, "Number13");
        printf("\n");
        PrintWood(Root);
        printf("\n");
        SearchCount(Root);
        RootDelete(Root);
        printf("After delete------\n");
        
        return 0;
    }
```

Здравствуйте. Проблема в том, что функция поиска должна искать по счетчику, находить элементы, которые повторяются два и более раз. С простым поиском по ключу проблем не возникает. В функцию RootDelete должно передаться возвращаемое значение из SerchCount, но передается только один элемент.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос не понял, что не работает, в чём ошибка?

Comment: У вас функция `SearchCount()` присваиваниями `SC->left = SearchCount(SC->left);` и `SC->right = SearchCount(SC->right);`  безнадежно портит  исходное дерево (из-за `if (SC == NULL) { return SC; }`)

Comment: Вы функцию `SearchCount` реализовали для вывода **всех** найденных элементов. И она возвращает просто корень дерева. Непонятна ваша проблема.

Comment: Мне надо что-бы она вернула все элементы, которые повторяются два и более раза. Проблема в том, что я не могу это сделать по счётчику count. Выполнение обрывается, когда левая ветка доходит до конца, а как перейти на правую? Не могу сообразить.